# Wait until the page loads protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, protractor

I have a login screen and when I press the Login button goes to the dashboard page. However, I often miss my timeout. Is there any possibility that when the button is pressed wait for the page to load?

my method in app.po.ts

```
login() {
 element(by.name('username')).sendKeys(browser.params[0].UserName);
 element(by.name('password')).sendKeys(browser.params[0].Password);
 element(by.partialButtonText('SignIn')).click();
 browser.sleep(5000);
}
```

Test is done here app.e2e-spec.ts

```
it('should be able to login', () => {
 page.navigateToHome();
 page.login();
 page.browserSleep();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `browser.wait` method to wait for a specific item inside your dashboard to appear, something like:

```
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(someElement), 10000, "Dashboard never loaded");
```

Comment: I was wondering is there any other ways more deterministic, I mean like a promise or something?

Comment: the first part of `wait` needs a promise, so you can change it with any method.

Comment: And is there a way to wait for the whole page to load?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using protractor 4 or above angular 4 in can take advantages of `async` and `await`

so your lofin function is a async function and while calling you will wait it to finish the async call.

```
async login() {
 element(by.name('username')).sendKeys(browser.params[0].UserName);
 element(by.name('password')).sendKeys(browser.params[0].Password);
 element(by.partialButtonText('SignIn')).click();
 browser.sleep(5000);
}


it('should be able to login', async () => {
 await page.navigateToHome();
 await page.login();
 // page.browserSleep(); you dont need to use page sleep as its not requred
});
```

You may need to define